# Getting FW/1 version info

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, fw1

I have been able to get other system information, but how do I get FW/1 version info? I have tried

#### Application info

```
<cfoutput>
<p><b>Java Version:</b> #CreateObject("java", "java.lang.System").getProperty("java.version")#</p>
<p><b>ColdFusion Version:</b> #server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion#</p>
<p><b>FW/1 Version:</b> </p>

</cfoutput>

<cfdump var="#application#">
```

[image: Application Info Dump]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look it up in `framework.cfc`. It's in the `variables` scope:

```
#variables._FW1_VERSION#
```